# x11vnc only show a small window size of remote machine

Tags: vnc, x11vnc

I am using x11vnc and it was working well and fit my entire monitor, the resolution of remote machine and my own host are both same which 1920x1080.
I had one reboot just now and the windows size had become very small and all actions super laggy.
Any idea to bring it back to full screen?

Command to start x11vnc

```
/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared
```

[image: Surrounding black space is the empty space of my host's monitor]

Comment: Does this thread help you here?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317053/x11vnc-change-resolution

Comment: @John It doesn't help, `-geometry` flag only stretch the small windows to my desired resolution, it is not the "real resolution"

Comment: I wasn't certain. I thought it might be worth a read, however.